# iOS Loading images from HTTP

Tags: ios, swift, app-transport-security

Is it possible to download an image from any website?

My problem is `App Transport Security`, because it is impossible to use domain exceptions for the whole internet, and unsecure ( and probably forbidden by Apple ) to bypass ATS.

HTTPS works fine, but what if user wants to save an image from HTTP?

Comment: Just disable ATS.

Comment: Disabling ATS is not forbidden. If your use case involves downloading images from arbitrary HTTP-based sited, doing so is really your only choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not forbidden, but at some point, Apple may ask you to provide justification for why you are lowering security of your app by using an ATS exception.

To allow HTTP connections to a single domain, which sounds like what you need, simply add the following to your Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

The key is to limit your exceptions to as narrow of a scope as possible.  In this case, you are limiting to only allow insecure (HTTP) connections to the domain of the server that hosts your images.

Comment: Single domain is not useful here, because if my app, for example, is a photo collage, it would require access to any domain.

Comment: If you don’t know the domains ahead of time (there’s not a predefined list of domains from which you are pulling images, you will have to disable ATS completely. Just be prepared to answer Apple if / when they ask why you have to disable ATS for all domains.   I think you likely have a valid justification, but only Apple knows what they are going to allow when they start enforcing rules they’ve been talking about for the past few years.

Comment: I guess there is no solution. It all depends on willingness of the Apple and current rules. Above code may help someone, so I'll pick it as an answer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "no solution".  The documented solution by Apple is to disable ATS and provide justification for why you cannot limit your ATS exceptions per domain.  You have an answer for that, so it should be enough.